# php simple html dom - finding all images specific div

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I am trying to find all images in a div in an html file. I am able to get the div content into a variable called $content. I figured I would then just do the same call and search for all images as I would search any other html file.

**So how would I search the images in a specific div in an html file?** or for later use. **HOW would i search the contents I have already gotten from a simple html dom call?** In this case how would I search the var called $content using simple html dom?

```
$theLink = $_GET[l];
$html = file_get_html("$theLink");
$content = $html->find('div[class=txt]');


foreach($content->find('img') as $element) /// Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object
echo $element->src . '<br>';
```

Comment: `->find('div[class=txt'] img')`? `$content` is going to be a NODEList of results from your find call. It's not a node, so won't have a find() call. `foreach($content as $node) { $node->find('img') }` would work.

Comment: `foreach ($html->find('div[class=txt'] img') as $img) { ... }`

Comment: This worked. Thank you. Actually what I am really try to do is abstract html from a blog and make it mobile. I am trying to add percentage style to all img tags. I am trying to add this attribute --style="width: 50%;  Any ideas on the best way to do this?